# iOS best way to store images

Tags: ios, image

So, i just want to know what the best way to display image from URL.

I have to display few post from the server into my iOS app using UITableView with title and image in it.

I had already created the WebServer for my app and fetching is done through TBXML and using Core Data to store the title and description from the server.

and i saw some library available to cache the image like https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Now my question is that how can i display image from the URL ?
And what is the best method to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Several ways: Download images to document directory and show from there. Use SDWebImage (It also cache the images: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Thank for the reply Midhun. 
do you have any idea about FastImageCache ?

Comment: No, Hearing about that library first name, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write your own code.  Using a library will work but it will be generic and by definition slower than what you can write for your specific use case.

You are far, far better off learning the few lines of code it takes to download an image and display it.  Learn how to use a `NSURLSession`.  Learn how to consume `NSData` and turn it into a `UIImage`.  Learn how to use a `NSNotification` or a block to propagate the loaded image to your user interface.

Your code will be stronger and you will become a better developer.